# webpack: how to include link to css file with inlined (base64) urls

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Input:

1) Webpack 3.

2) Css file with urls to OTF font files.

3) HtmlWebpackPlugin

Output:

1) Html that contains link to style file produces from css and with inlined base64 fonts.

2) This css is copied to build dir while build.

What plugins should I use do this?

I found it really cumbersome to figure out what plugins and workflow should be used shuld there be used copy-webpack-plugin and html-webpack-include-assets-plugin, I didn't see the obvious straightforward solution for this seemed to be a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `webpack.base.conf.js` like this

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  }, 
  module: {
    rules: [ 
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 500000, // <------ increase the limit so all fonts use Data-URI
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }, 
    ]
  },
```